# putting an condition in xslt to deal with underscores

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am reading an xml and in xml there is a tag as shown below..

```
<tradeRefId>10352684-2</tradeRefId>
```

now it's value can also be ..

<`tradeRefId>10353984</tradeRefId>`

so to extract this tag from the xml i have written the xsl as shown below..

```
<Contract_Id>
                <xsl:value-of select="eurr:tradeRefId"/>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(eurr:tradeRefId, '-')" /> -->
                </Contract_Id>
```

now i want to put a check such that if in the value of this tag if '_' is coming then it should not be included so 10352684-2 should be taken as 10352684 so please advise how can I put such check
please advise

Comment: Writing in complete, grammatical sentences would increase your chances of being understood and receiving help.  Specifically, rewrite this: *now i want to put a check such that if in the value of this tag if '_' is coming then it should not be included so 10352684-2 should be taken as 10352684 so please advise how can I put such check*

Comment: @kjhughes yeah sure next time i will make sure that grammatical error should not be there what i was trying to communicate that i dont want '_' to be included at all .

Comment: It's not too late to fix things here -- use the **edit** link.  Lose the text speak, clarify how dashes (`-`) are to be treated different than underscores (`_`), and provide specific examples.  Lots of people here can help you, but you have to make it clear what you need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this should work:

```
<Contract_Id>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(eurr:tradeRefId, '_')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(eurr:tradeRefId, '_')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="eurr:tradeRefId"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</Contract_Id>
```

I'm not sure from your question if you are trying to detect a hyphen: **-** or an underscore **_**  The XSL above will work for underscores, so substitute as necessary.

Comment: Or if you need to remove both, replace the entire `xsl:choose` with `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(.,'_'),'_'),'-'),'-')"/>`.

Comment: @Daniel Haley that certainly works! I might say it's a little tough to read. I guess it's a little awkward as you have to append a _ or - to cater for when the element does not contain a _ or -. However as we've not gotten any further clarification from the original asker of the question on what they actually want, at this point it seems we are talking to ourselves.